# Getting the next latest created ID

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I'm working on a stored procedure, see [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607079/stored-procedure-for-adding-a-movie)  that explains what I want.

I've created a sproc that adds a movie to the database, and runs separate sprocs from within to create for example a cast for the movie and adds a genre to it (stored in a separate table).

When running the sproc "NewMovie" a new movie gets added to the database, and the ID of that movie is used in the two other sprocs that I run after the movie is added. The problem is that  after for example the cast is created, @@IDENTITY refers to CastID, but I need to use the movie ID again after this.

Is it some way that I can get the next latest created ID, or how could I accomplish what I want?

The code so far can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/T1NFqbyS) if someone has the time to look through it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Next latest created` phrase makes no sense

Comment: @zerkms: sorry, my english isn 't the best. do you have any suggestions for a new title?

Comment: but i'm not talking about the latest id, i'm talking about the id before the latest ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of curiosity, you already have @MovieID in `usp_NewMovie` - why not just use that as a parameter to `usp_AddGenre` and `usp_AddMovieRole`?

Also you might be better off using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead of `@@IDENTITY` http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/

I made some updates to your code here: http://pastebin.com/rhhrGsuB

Comment: I guess you're refering to "@MovieID = @@IDENTITY" inside the sproc? That was an error in my code (it's not allowed to do like that). :/

Comment: You need a `SELECT` or `SET` before it. Try `SELECT @MovieID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

Comment: Great, that works like a charm! Should I change @@IDENTITY to SCOPE_IDENTITY() in all places in the code?

Comment: I would recommend it. If you check out the link in my answer, it mentions the following: `In other words, it[SCOPE_IDENTITY()] will return the last identity value that you explicitly created, rather than any identity that was created by a trigger or a user defined function.`